# Regex to replace characters

Tags: regex

I have the following example `'H2J','H3N','H3N','H2J','H2P','H2K','H2J','H2K','H3N'` but I want to have `(H2J),(H3N),(H3N),(H2J),(H2P),(H2K),(H2J),(H2K),(H3N)` can anyone show me what regex would replace the single quotes with brackets?

I'm using TextWrangler on Mac.

Comment: I'm surprised to see that no one mentioned here that **we are not a code writing service**. I usually find this on most questions

Comment: @Prasanna Yes, this was my mistake, I got caught up in the problem.

Comment: While I understand this is not a code writing service it does help as a gateway into learning or starting to get concepts from the help received. At the least it sparks curiosity and a hunger to learn more so as to reach the same answer given by the person assisting. That's my take anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 /'([A-Z0-9]+)'/\($1\)/g
```

This is the match

1. a `'`
2. A sequence of one or more alphanumerics  `[A-Z0-9]+`
3. a `'`

The sequence is in parenthesis so we can capture it and use it in the replace

The replace is just

1. a `(`
2. The sequence captured above `$1`
3. a `)`

So in your editor, the search term would be:

```
'([A-Z0-9]+)'
```

And the replace term would be:

```
 \($1\)
```

And replace all.  Check the format for replacing groups, in some editors it is `\1` instead of `$1`

Comment: Thanks Paul, is the regex supposed to be `/'([A-Z0-9]+)'\/\($1\)/g` note the extra left slash. If so, I'm not getting any matches? If not, I'm not getting a match either way. 
`

Comment: No, the extra backslash isn't needed.  Note that this is a standard format regex, you may neeed to split it when using in an editor.  I'll update.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I get it now. Your suggestion worked and I also used another site  regextester.com to make further edits - which was recommended by another user here.